# can we achieve exactly one processing of message using spring kafka batch listener?

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I am trying to achieve exactly once processing of each message on kafka topic. Here is my configuration:

```
config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");    
config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 120000);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 25);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MIN_BYTES_CONFIG, 4096000);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG, 120000);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 600000);  
config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, 8192000);
```

I have set `Acknolwedgement Mode` as MANUAL & concurrency to 2.

Yet it consumes messages more than once. Has anyone faced this issue.
Also, with above configuration, consumer always receives only one message in one batch. I have tried increasing `fetch.min.bytes` and `fetch.max.wait.ms`, but it doesn't have any impact.

The problem with batch configuration is resolved after I made change to ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory as followed:

```
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
    new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

factory.setBatchListener(true);
factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3600000);
```

factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(org.springframework.kafka.listner.ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
    factory.setMessageConverter(new BatchMessagingMessageConverter(stringJsonMessageConverter()));

Answer (score 1):

To get exactly once semantics, you have to use [transactions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#transactions).

However, exactly once semantics only applies to

```
read from Kafka -> process -> write to Kafka
```

and even then, it only applies to whole flow (read/process/write).

The read and process steps alone could be called multiple times for the same record (if the process or write fails). The only guarantee is that the whole thing will only be processed exactly once.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I am doing the same, I am reading from the input topic, processing data and writing to the output topic. If I used transactions, will it have any impact on performance? Also, do you have any example how to implement consumerRebalanceListener as I want to safely commit / acknowledge offsets in case of rebalance.

Comment: `>will it have any impact on performance? ` There will be some additional overhead, depending on the batch size. I don't know what you mean about committing offsets after a rebalance - if there was a rebalance, the partitions may have been given to a new instance. You should ask a new question since it's not related to this one.

Comment: are they any factors which can overcome this overhead? I have kept 100 as my batch size as my first try. The processing is compute intensive and on average it takes about 500 ms to process each request. can you point me in right direction to achieve maximum throughput.

Comment: If it's compute intensive, it's unlikely that the extra overhead of using transactions is significant.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka offers at least once processing by default. So, implementing idempotence in your consumer can also be effectively exactly-once. Lets say your system looks like

```
producer -> topic1 -> consumer1 -> topic2 -> consumer2 -> topic3 -> consumer3
```

Lets say the final processing is done in consumer3. Then even if the intermediate consumers process the message multiple times, adding idempotence in consumer3 would make sure each message is processed exactly once.

However, this assumes that it's okay to process the same message multiple times in the intermediate consumers. This approach might be easier in a simpler system with only a handful of consumers/topics. If the number of consumers increases, adding idempotence checks at each consumer could get cumbersome.